# How to use MAXIMUM_ALLOWED properly?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-kernel, nt-native-api

I have created a small framework that provides a unified API to multiple file systems/APIs (namely Win32, Posix, NFS). Said API is somewhat similar to Posix -- to access a file you need to "open" it providing a hint for intended purpose (`r`, `w` or `rw`). Something like `open_file("/abc/log.txt", access::rw)`.

Supporting Win32 API in this framework gives me a headache due to "declarative" nature of Win32 -- you are supposed to know upfront which operations you plan to perform on given handle and pass related `dwDesiredAccess` into related `(Nt)CreateFile()` call. Unfortunately framework has no idea what operation client is going to perform (i.e. change-owner, write-attributes, etc) besides generic `r/w/rw` hint. And I am not willing to let Win32 concepts to leak into my framework (i.e. I don't like adding `dwDesiredAccess` equivalent into my `open_file()`).

Here is what I've tried:

**1. MAXIMUM_ALLOWED**

*Idea:* Open related handles with MAXIMUM_ALLOWED -- I'll get everything I could and if some right is missing, related operation (e.g. `set_mime()`) will simply fail with `access denied`.

*Problems:*

- it doesn't work with read-only files or volumes (`(Nt)CreateFile()` fails with `access denied`)
- MSDN [warns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) that if defragmentation is in progress on FAT volume -- trying to open a directory this way will fail
- in general it seems that using `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` is frowned upon for some reason

**2. Reopen object when necessary**

*Idea:* Represent `r/w/rw` though `GENERIC_READ` and `GENERIC_WRITE` and for all operations that require additional access (e.g. `delete()` requires `DELETE`) reopen the object with required access.

*Problems:*

- Reopening object is not cheap
- changes made via second object can be silently overwritten, for example:

  - `set_mtime()` reopens the file with `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|SYNCHRONIZE`
  - calls `NtSetInformationFile(... FileBasicInformation)` to update metadata and closes the handle
  - later original handle gets closed, it causes data flush and silently overwrites `ModifiedTime` previously set by `set_mtime()`

**3. Duplicate handle instead of reopening object**

*Idea:* same as in previous section, but instead of reopening object -- duplicate original handle (asking for new access):

```
HANDLE h;
HANDLE hp = GetCurrentProcess();
CHECK_WIN32( DuplicateHandle(hp, hFile, hp, &h, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, 0) );
```

*Problems:*

- Duplicating (and closing) file handle every time I need to perform (a non-plain-read/write) operation seem to be excessive and somewhat expensive
- `DuplicateHandle()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) warns (without giving any details) that asking for additional access **may** fail. It has been working fine in all use cases I checked it for (typically asking for things like `DELETE`/`FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` on handles opened with `GENERIC_READ`), but apparently Win32 API provides no guarantees :-/

... otherwise approach seem to be working.

**Bottomline:**

I am looking for a way to address `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` issues. (Or suggestions for alternative approach, maybe?)

Comment: About [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle): "*in other cases, DuplicateHandle cannot create a handle with more access rights than the original. For example, a file handle created with the GENERIC_READ access right cannot be duplicated so that it has both the GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE access right*".

Comment: @dxiv yeah, I saw this. Unfortunately MSDN doesn't specify any details and in my use cases asking for additional access (i.e. `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` or `DELETE` when object is opened with `GENERIC_READ`) so far always worked... I am not comfortable with this approach at all, but I couldn't find anything better :-\

Comment: ReOpenFile lets you open a new handle to a file with different access rights.

Comment: @RaymondChen `ReOpenFile()` creates new kernel file object, I just checked -- it is the same as case #2 with the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Here is [another reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037934/sharing-violation-with-multi-threaded-file-io-on-windows/68096871#68096871) why reopening file is not a good idea.

There is no way to use `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` reliably -- R/O files and volumes cause it to error. Poorly designed feature.

Another approach is to get minimum access and "expand" it as required (by re-opening file with new `dwAccessRequired` flag). This does not work:

- if you open file temporarily some changes made through new handle (e.g. `mtime` modification) will be wiped out later when original handle is closed (and underlying kernel object flushes data to disk)
- if you try to replace old handle with new one this means expensive flush (on old handle close) + MT synchronization which means I can't efficiently use my `file` object from multiple threads (I know that right now due to `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` all operations are serialized anyway, but it will be fixed in near term)

Alas, `DuplicateHandle()` can't grant new access -- so this won't help either.

Basically, all I need is a thread-safe `BOOL ExtendAccess(HANDLE h, DWORD dwAdditionalAccess)` function. It looks like you can't have it even via NT API -- possible only in kernel mode.

Luckily this framework is always used under privileged account, which means I can enable `SE_BACKUP_NAME`, use `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT`, over-request access (with minimal fallback in case of read-only volume) and avoid dealing with restrictive DACLs. Ah, and yes, deal with `ReadOnly` attribute in `delete()`. Still haven't decided what to do if user wants to open read-only file for writing...

I ended up with this:

```
W32Handle open_file_(HANDLE hparent, UNICODE_STRING zwpath, access a, disposition d, truncate t)
{
    ...
    ACCESS_MASK access = [a]() -> ACCESS_MASK {
        switch(a)
        {
        case access::r  : return GENERIC_READ;
        case access::w  : [[fallthrough]];                      // MSDN suggests to use GENERIC_READ with GENERIC_WRITE over network (performance reasons)
        case access::rw : return GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE;
        }
        UNREACHEABLE;
    }();

    constexpr DWORD write_access = FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|DELETE|WRITE_OWNER;    // we want to always have these (for apply, unlink, chown, etc)

    access |= write_access;
    access |= SYNCHRONIZE|READ_CONTROL|ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY;                  // add "read DACL/SACL" rights (for full_metadata)

    ULONG flags = FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT;

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, &zwpath, 0, hparent, NULL);

    HANDLE h;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK io;
    NTSTATUS r = ZwCreateFile(&h, access, &oa, &io, NULL, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, disposition, flags, NULL, 0);
    if (r == STATUS_SUCCESS) return W32Handle(h);

    if (r == STATUS_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECTED)      // try again without write flags
    {
        access &= ~write_access;
        r = ZwCreateFile(&h, access, &oa, &io, NULL, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, disposition, flags, NULL, 0);
        if (r == STATUS_SUCCESS) return W32Handle(h);
    }

    HR_THROW_(HRESULT_FROM_NT(r), "%s: Failed to open file", __func__);
}
```

Overall terrible API, a spaghetti of special cases. I wish I had my own SMB client.